# How do I concatenate strings from a list in a bash script?

Tags: script, shell-script, bash-scripting

As an example:

```
List="A B C D"
for I in $List
do
    OUT=$OUT" -$I"
done
```

When I run this the result is:

```
" -A -B -C -D"
```

but want it to be:

```
"-A -B -C -D"
```

How do I concatenate without the leading space?

This btw is an argument list to a script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [conditional parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
List="A B C D"
for I in $List
do
    OUT=${OUT:+$OUT }-$I
done
```

The expression `${OUT:+$OUT }` expands to nothing if OUT is not set or empty; if it is set to a nonempty value, then it expands to that value followed by a space.

However, this sort of operation - treating a whitespace-separated string as a list - is fraught with possible problems: quoting, values that unexpectedly contain spaces themselves, etc.   You would be better off using an array:

```
List=(A B C D)
for I in "${List[@]}"
do    
    OUT=${OUT:+$OUT }-$I
done
```

Depending on what you're doing with `$OUT`, it might make sense to make it an array as well:

```
List=(A B C D)
OUT=()
for I in "${List[@]}"; do
  OUT+=("-$I")
done
```

Then you would use `"${OUT[@]}"` to pass on the elements of the array to another command as separate arguments.

To go back to your original version, in this specific case you could also just use `sed` and skip the bash loop entirely:

```
OUT=$(sed -E 's/^| /&-/g' <<<"$List")
```

The regex `^|`  matches either the beginning of the string or a space; the replacement `&-` means "whatever the regex matched" (the empty string at the start, or a space) followed by a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the leading space using a command after the for-loop, such as

```
OUT=${OUT# }
```

Leading to

```
List="A B C D"
for I in $List
do
    OUT=$OUT" -$I"
done
OUT=${OUT# }
```